# How to set the termination time in OptaPlanner

Tags: optaplanner

I run the vehicle routing OptaPlanner example and the program terminates after 5 minutes but I'd like it to do more iterations.

Even after changing the line in the `vehicleRoutingSolverConfig.xml` file to "`minutesSpentLimit 6000 minutesSpentLimit`" (with the appropriate brackets of course - it does not display properly here of I just paste it in) , it still terminates after 5 minutes.

I use IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.4 Community edition, Windows 10 and OptaPlanner 6.4.0.

I have tried to put junk in the configuration file, expecting an error, but it still runs and terminates after 5 minutes.

My guess is I'm doing something stupid so that the program somehow does not read the configuration file and uses the default solver configuration.

I'll appreciate help very much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that must work.

Try setting a breakpoint after the `SolverFactory` creation and check its `getSolverConfig().getTerminationConfig()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion Geoffrey, but I *overcame* rather than solved my problem.

I downloaded OptaPlanner 7.0.0 Beta1 and it's doing what I expect now. It's been running for 25 minutes without terminating now. I'm happy.

I think there was probably something wrong with my IntelliJ settings previously?